# Handle ORACLE Exceptions

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, ora-01400

I need to handle the [ORA-01400 error](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01400.php) (cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA"."TABLE_NAME"."COLUMN_NAME") ) using a exception handle.

ORACLE Predefine a few Exceptions like (ACCESS_INTO_NULL, ZERO_DIVIDE and so on), but apparently does not define an Exception for the ORA-01400 error, how do I handle this particular error code?

I need something like this (other suggestions are accepted).

```
....
 ...     
 INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (CODE, NAME) VALUES (aCode,aName);
 COMMIT;
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NULL_VALUES THEN /* i don't know this value , exist?*/
       Do_MyStuff();
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       raise_application_error(SQLCODE,MY_OWN_FORMAT_EXCEPTION(SQLCODE,SQLERRM),TRUE); 
    END;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The pre-defined PL/SQL exceptions are *special* to Oracle. You really can't mess with those. When you want to have a set of predefined exceptions of your own you can't declare them "globally" like the standard ones. Instead, create an *exceptions* package which has all of the exception declarations and use that in your *application* code.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_exceptions
AS
  insert_null_into_notnull EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(insert_null_into_notnull, -1400);

  update_null_to_notnull EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(update_null_to_notnull, -1407);
END my_exceptions;
/
```

Now use the exception defined in the package

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE use_an_exception AS
BEGIN
  -- application specific code ...
  NULL;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN my_exceptions.insert_null_into_notnull THEN
     -- application specific handling for ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into (%s)
     RAISE;
END;
/
```

Source: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Exception

Answer (score 3):

you can define your own exceptions, like variables (they will have the same scope as other variables so you can define package exception, etc...):

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     NULL_VALUES EXCEPTION;
  3     PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(NULL_VALUES, -1400);
  4  BEGIN
  5     INSERT INTO t VALUES (NULL);
  6  EXCEPTION
  7     WHEN null_values THEN
  8        dbms_output.put_line('null value not authorized');
  9  END;
 10  /

null value not authorized

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Comment: Vincent, I already knew this, the problem of this solution is that I need to define an exception for each particular table. I am looking for a way to serve for any table in my schema.

Comment: create a schema-level trigger, to handle this custom exception

Comment: @RRUZ: I don't really understand, you can use this exception with ANY table. If you define it in a package header, you can use it everywhere (i-e: it will be **exactly** like a predefined oracle exception)

Comment: I think the missing piece is to examine the SQLERRM to find the table/column which is causing the exception.

Comment: @Adam, I'm not interested in the table/column wich cause the exception, just i need handle this particular exception like ORACLE Does with the Predefined exceptions.

Comment: Ok...I think I get it. You don't want to have to declare the exception in every PL/SQL block...you want to declare it once and have it "known" system-wide?

Comment: Yes @Adam, Something like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can handle exception by its code like this:

```
....
 ...
 INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (CODE, NAME) VALUES (aCode,aName);   
 COMMIT;   
   EXCEPTION   
     WHEN OTHERS THEN   
       IF SQLCODE = -1400 THEN
         Do_MyStuff();
       ELSE
         raise_application_error(SQLCODE,MY_OWN_FORMAT_EXCEPTION(SQLCODE,SQLERRM),TRUE);
       END IF;
    END;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (CODE, NAME) VALUES (aCode,aName);
 COMMIT;  

      EXCEPTION
         WHEN NULL_VALUES /* i don't know this value , exist?*/
           emesg := SQLERRM;
           dbms_output.put_line(emesg); 
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
           emesg := SQLERRM;
           dbms_output.put_line(emesg);
         END;
```

---

SQLERRM shows the sql error message

http://www.psoug.org/reference/exception_handling.html