# Function resumes execution after exception in subprogram

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

I am raising an exception in a subprogram, and I'm expecting to see the calling function halt execution at this point. However, the calling function continues processing as if nothing happened, and I don't understand why.

My function looks something like this:

```
FUNCTION getFooCursor (i_blah IN VARCHAR)
    RETURN t_ref_cursor
IS
    v_sum_variable  NUMBER;
BEGIN
    --lookup number
    v_sum_variable := getNumber (i_blah);

    --call function that raises NO_DATA_FOUND exception
    doRaiseException();

    --the exception handler is only supposed to catch for this block
    BEGIN
        --do stuff and end up with a cursor
        RETURN barCursor(v_sum_variable);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            --set some variables
    END
END;
```

Let's say `doRaiseException()` looks like this:

```
PROCEDURE doRaiseException ()
IS
BEGIN
    RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
END;
```

When I debug this function in TOAD, it helpfully informs me that the NO_DATA_FOUND exception has been raised. However, it then immediately carries on to execute the next line (where `barCursor()` is called) and the function finishes as if nothing ever went wrong.

I have tried replacing `doRaiseException();` directly with `RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;` for testing purposes (it actually does more than that) and this stops execution within `getFooCursor()` but whatever SQL calls it again completely ignores the exception.

Is this just how exceptions work in PL/SQL? Don't they bubble up as they do in Java or C#? Perhaps I am missing something crucial about exceptions in Oracle. How do I get an exception to bubble up to the host?

---

Here is my Oracle version (as returned from v$version):

```
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production                          
CORE    10.2.0.5.0  Production                                      
TNS for HPUX: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production                   
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
```

Comment: Are you sure your first function looks exactly like that? Exceptions work as you suppose and "bubble up", so you must be catching it somewhere.

Comment: @Ben: I've added some information to my example that suddenly seemed a lot more relevant after reading your comment. Obvious in retrospect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of exceptions is correct.  However, this is one notable exception to how exceptions work: NO_DATA_FOUND is silently ignored in a SQL context.  This is a "feature", because this is how Oracle tells other processes that there is no more data to read.

For custom exceptions, you will probably need to catch NO_DATA_FOUND and raise it as different exception.  This is usually a horrible way to handle exceptions but there is no good alternative here.

```
SQL> create or replace function function1 return number is
  2  begin
  3     raise no_data_found;
  4     return 1;
  5  end;
  6  /

Function created.

SQL> select function1 from dual;

 FUNCTION1
----------


1 row selected.

SQL> create or replace function function2 return number is
  2  begin
  3     raise no_data_found;
  4     return 1;
  5     exception when no_data_found then
  6             raise_application_error(-20000, 'NO_DATA_FOUND raised');
  7  end;
  8  /

Function created.

SQL> select function2 from dual;
select function2 from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: NO_DATA_FOUND raised
ORA-06512: at "JHELLER.FUNCTION2", line 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions work as you suppose and "bubble up", so you must be catching it somewhere.

That's what's happening... you're catching *every* exception, which isn't the best practice. You can either ensure you only [catch a specific exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020450/oracle-pl-sql-raise-user-defined-exception-with-custom-sqlerrm) if you define one yourself. However, that doesn't seem to be what you want to do here. You want to re-raise only a *single* exception.

So, you could [define a custom exception in a separate package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975290/handle-oracle-exceptions), raise that in your sub-program and then do something like this in your calling block:

```
begin
   RaiseException;

exception
   when my_exception_package.my_exception then
      raise;
   when others then
      DoSomethingElse;
end;
```

That way you catch the exceptions you want to raise and then re-raise them. If the exception is different then you continue with your current programme flow.