# PLSQL : varchar variable becomes null without any reason

Tags: oracle, plsql

trying to migrate some pgpl/SQL to psql oracle function, i discover a strange behaviour i cant explain at all.

Here is my function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION small_distinct(
   tableName IN varchar, 
   cols IN COL_ARRAY,     
   whereCond IN varchar
)
RETURN varchar 
IS
  nbcols PLS_INTEGER;
  currentcolnumber PLS_INTEGER;
  currentcol varchar(100);
  firstcol varchar(100);
  sqlpart varchar(4000);
  firstquery_str VARCHAR2(4000);
  query_str VARCHAR2(4000);
  big_query_str VARCHAR2(10000);
  firstresult varchar(100);
  opt SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  firstcol:= cols(1);
  sqlpart := firstcol;
  nbcols := cols.COUNT;
  currentcolnumber :=  2;
  big_query_str := 'SELECT * from ( SELECT '|| sqlpart ||' FROM '||tableName||' WHERE ' ||    whereCond|| ' ORDER BY '|| firstcol || ') WHERE ROWNUM = 1';

  while currentcolnumber <= nbcols loop
     sqlpart := sqlpart || ', ' ||cols(currentcolnumber);
     currentcolnumber := currentcolnumber +1;
  end loop;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * from (SELECT '|| firstcol ||' FROM '||tableName ||' WHERE ' || whereCond|| ' ORDER BY '|| firstcol || ') WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ' INTO firstresult;

  while firstresult is not null 
  loop
    big_query_str := big_query_str || ' UNION ' || 'SELECT * from ( SELECT '|| sqlpart ||' FROM '||tableName||' WHERE '|| firstcol ||' > '''|| firstresult||''' AND ' || whereCond|| ' ORDER BY '|| firstcol || ') WHERE ROWNUM  = 1  ';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * from ( SELECT ' || firstcol ||' FROM '||tableName ||' WHERE '|| firstcol ||' > '''|| firstresult||''' AND '|| whereCond|| ' ORDER BY '|| firstcol || ') WHERE ROWNUM = 1' INTO firstresult;
  end loop;

  return big_query_str;
END small_distinct;
```

This function compile well, but my varchar `big_query_str` is null when the function return.

As you can see in my function, there is no possibility this `varchar` can be null since i initialize it with a value **at the line 18**

I tried to remove so lines to discover what the problem could be, the return value is not null only **if i remove the while loop** ( around line 24 )

Do someone at least explain me what sort of event can reset a varchar in PL/SQL ?

Comment: from which client are you running it?

Comment: How are you calling it, and what are you assigning the return value to? If that assignment target is smaller than 10,000 chars (why `varchar` rather than the more normal `varchar2`?), or you're calling it from plain SQL, the assignment would fail; possibly you're squashing the ORA-06502 error you get at that point? Or the string ends up as > 10,000 chars, and your caller is still squashing that error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function resumes execution after exception in subprogram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568539/function-resumes-execution-after-exception-in-subprogram)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an exception handler round the firstresult line.

`BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * from ( SELECT ' || firstcol ||' FROM '||tableName ||' WHERE '|| firstcol ||' > '''|| firstresult||''' AND '|| whereCond|| ' ORDER BY '|| firstcol || ') WHERE ROWNUM = 1' INTO firstresult;
    EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN
    EXIT;
    END;`

Looks to me like it will keep going to the last record, then get a no_data_found as there aren't any more records where "firstcol > firstresult".

Comment: Ok... i cant verify now, but its look like totally true. Indeed i come from PGPL/SQL and this situation is not possible. I forgot that select into MUST return something and my algorythm was to let it fail :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to include this loop into the BEGIN/EXCEPTION/END. Is it possible that in this loop error occurs and `return big_query_str` is not executed?

```
BEGIN
  while firstresult is not null 
  loop
    big_query_str := big_query_str ||........
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE....
  end loop;
  return big_query_str;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN 
     return 'ERROR';      
END;
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but more informative is to return `'ERROR: ' || SQLERRM`

Comment: thank you both for your time :), it helped my advance on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but your big_query_str is defined as a varchar2 of 10,000 length. The maximum allowable length of varchar2 when returning to SQL is 4000 characters. So, perhaps, that is an issue? Can you try defining big_query_str to a CLOB type and then returning it from the function (after making necessary changes to function)

Comment: I thought the max value was 32000 in plsql ? But aniway, this solution isn't good enought, i can easily break 32k caracters in some situations. In my real function i dont return big_query_str but i execute it to return it as a sys cursor.

Comment: after some more research, for building request than are bigger than 32k caracters i can use this syntax : execute immediate sqlpart1 || sqlpart2. I'm sure i could manage to cut my request.